# Javascript array value from where?

Tags: javascript

So guys i need your help, look at this script:

```
function findMax() {
  var i;

  var max = -Infinity;

  for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    if (arguments[i] > max) {
      max = arguments[i];
    }
  }

  return max;
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = findMax(4, 5, 10);
```

Result=10

The question is how the program knows which number of the three from arguments goes into argument[i]? I dont see it giving value to it anywhere and it somehow compares this array to variable "max" to find out the max number. Hope somebody can explain it.

Comment: The `for` loop iterates over an `arguments` object. In javascript, `arguments` returns an object containing the arguments passed to the current function. In this case, arguments is equal to `{ '0': 4, '1': 5, '2': 10 }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each function has a parameter called `arguments`, which is an array like object and contains the parameters you pass when you call the function.

As it is stated more formally [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments):

> The arguments object is a local variable available within all
>   functions. You can refer to a function's arguments within the function
>   by using the arguments object. This object contains an entry for each
>   argument passed to the function, the first entry's index starting at
>   0.

```js
function test(){
    for(var i = 0; i<arguments.length; i++){
       console.log(arguments[i]);
    }
}

test('a');
test(1,2,3);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `arguments` object is an intrinsic, automatic value inside any function. The object is *like* an array of the actual parameters passed to the function upon invocation.

If you have a function, therefore, and you call it with a list of values, the function can examine those values via the `arguments` object.

Answer (score 0):

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

for an explanation of the arguments object.

It's done automatically by Javascript. The arguments are placed in the array in the order they are given to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Arguments contains all the arguments passed to the function, so in the loop it will cycle them

Answer (score 0):

> The question is how the program knows which number of the three from arguments goes into argument[i]?

This is determined at runtime. The `arguments` object is automatically and dynamically created when the call takes place.

> I dont see it giving value to it anywhere and it somehow compares this array to variable "max" to find out the max number.

Its members will be the exact number of arguments passed. If you pass 3 arguments, it will be created with members `0`, `1` and `2`, referencing those three args.

So at this point, for purposes of iteration, you can treat it like an array, since it also gets its `.length` property populated with the total number of args.

Answer (score 0):

The `arguments` object is an Array-like object corresponding to the arguments passed to a function.

It contains among other things, a `length` property that is the the number of arguments passed to the function and an `[@@iterator]` property where like for `array` : `arguments[i]` contains and refers the element at the `i` index.

[The Function documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) gives more details :

> The `arguments` object is a local variable available within all
>   functions. You can refer to a function's arguments within the function
>   by using the `arguments` object. This object contains an entry for each
>   argument passed to the function, the first entry's index starting at
>   0. For example, if a function is passed three arguments, you can refer to them as follows:

```
arguments[0]
arguments[1]
arguments[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Beside the given explanation about [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments),

> The `arguments` object is a local variable available within all functions. You can refer to a function's arguments within the function by using the `arguments` object. This object contains an entry for each argument passed to the function, the first entry's index starting at 0.

you could take the first element of it as start value and iterate from the second on. The advantage is, you get a real value and if there is no argument, then you get `undefined` instead of `-Infinity`.

```js
function findMax() {
    var i,
        max = arguments[0];

    for (i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        if (arguments[i] > max) {
            max = arguments[i];
        }
    }
    return max;
}

console.log(findMax(4, 5, 10)); // 10
console.log(findMax());         // undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

> The question is how the program knows which number of the three from arguments goes into argument[I]?

Because that's what you are asking it to do ;-)

As quoted above, MDN has a great page describing what the arguments array is, how to access each of it's elements and touches on how to manipulate the arguments array.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Coming back to your code, the for loop is iterating over the arguments array so this line:

```
if (arguments[i] > max) {
```

is actually saying:

```
if (arguments[4] > max) {
if (arguments[5] > max) {
if (arguments[10] > max) {
```

At each iteration given the length of the arguments array (which in this case is 3)